# Selenium WebDriver on multi threads in Sidekiq

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, sidekiq

I have a question about Selenium WebDriver and its usage with multi threads. I have an app that fetches some data from websites so to do that I use Watir browser which uses Selenium WebDriver. I also have Sidekiq configured. My flow is that I enqueue a few jobs that initialize watir using chromedriver so at the same time there are 6 concurrent threads with Selenium WebDriver running. From time to time I notice some errors like: 
`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9519` or 
`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to bind to locking port 9514 within 45 seconds` or `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: failed to start a thread for the new session`. Is it related to the fact that Selenium isn't thread-safe? I thought that if I initialize the browser in different threads then it should work correctly but it doesn't. Is there a way to fix it somehow?

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'selenium/webdriver/remote/http/curb'

module Scrapers
  class Browser
    def run
      Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, watir_options)
    end

    private

    def chrome_args
      [
        '--ignore-certificate-errors',
        '--disable-popup-blocking',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--window-size=1024,768',
        '--disable-extensions'
      ]
    end

    def chrome_options
      chrome_bin = ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', nil)
      chrome_bin ? { 'chromeOptions' => { 'binary' => chrome_bin } } : {}
    end

    def watir_options
      {
        headless: true,
        timeout: 60,
        http_client: Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Curb.new,
        args: chrome_args
      }.merge!(chrome_options)
    end
  end
end
```

It mostly fails when invoking `run` method or when the object is already initialized and invoking `goto`.

Comment: Can you please include the code?

Comment: @Rajagopalan added

Comment: these 6 threads, are they all working upon the same instance of the browser?

Comment: @GenericSnake not really, every Sidekiq worker calls `Watir::Browser.new` to initialize a new instance of the browser

Comment: @user3014317 hmm, it is strange then, you're right that threads should work across separate browsers, and i cant find any other issues with the same port number. When these errors occur, does the program fail entirely, and is it on any particular thread, or is it straight away? 


(Maybe something silly like the class and the call for opening chrome both being `Browser` :D )

Comment: I don't have an answer for why these errors, other than it appears to be chromedriver itself, not Selenium or Watir. First, double check that you are using the latest chromedriver (I recommend using webdrivers gem to ensure it is always up to date). Also, most of us who run multiple sessions in parallel use this gem: https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests

Comment: each instance is calling chromedriver with the default port, so you have conflicts

Comment: did you manage to solve it? i have the same issue